# How to create a menu bar with hamburger menu and other icons in Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I want to create an app with a bar along the top on each screen, with a hamburger menu and other icons as seen here:

https://images.app.goo.gl/viV3EjFvRdWKAJ1u9

What's the best way to do this?

I've created a button to create the blue bar, I don't want it as a button but wasn't sure how else I'd go about it.

To then add the icons would I get images and then make them into buttons?

```
Button:
    background_normal: ""
    background_color: 0.2,0.6,1,1
    size_hint: 1, 0.125
    pos_hint: {"top": 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

The action bar you've shown follows Google's material design standards. You can use KivyMD which gives you access to these widgets right away! First you'll need to download KivyMD then use the `MDToolbar` widget.

Video on how to install KivyMD*: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kRWtSkIYPFI

Video on how to use the MDToolbar widget*: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ocfLcJ2ycIQ

*Disclaimer: I made these videos.

Comment: Thanks, these look really good! Unfortunately I'm running on Windows and it seems like it's going to be a lot of pain to get KivyMD to work on Windows?

Comment: Nope, it works on Windows as well. Just download from git using the command in the video, then don't use `sudo` when running `setup.py install`

Comment: you can also install KivyMD on windows with pip.

Comment: I installed with pip but am getting an error message from the .kv file: Unable to import package 'kivymd.navigationdrawer.NavigationLayout'

Comment: Solved it, I didn't need to import anything apparently. Not sure why this is though

Comment: Yep, the guy working on KivyMD changed some things it made it so you don't need to import anything now. In my video which unfortunately I made just before the change, you had to import the widgets. I made a note on the video for future people.